# Copying CSV File when integer exceeds maximum

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, typeerror

If this input exists in **a specific row**, for example DD in row `WORD4` (row 3), the program will then ask them to enter an integer and if this is over a certain number it will write it including the line.

Something like so:

```
a0,a1,a2,a3,a4    
JA,BV,PA,DD,6
```

The error received I did receive was:

```
TypeError: writerows() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

And

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Thanks to Joel Johnson and Stevieb for the solution to this problem!

**The solution is as followed, Thanks Joel Johnson:**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to use `with open('CSVFile2.csv', 'a') as f:` to write anything to the file(if you want to keep any content already in `CSVFile2.csv` or use `'w'` if you want to overwrite it).

Second, since you are only trying to write one row with format 
`['JA',BV','PA','DD','6']` use `writer.writerow()` instead of `writer.writerows()` else you will end up with `J,A,B,V,P,A,D,D,6` as your output.

Third, simply append `integer_input` to `row` before passing it to `writer.writerow()` also note that it needs to be in str() format

If you have any other questions I would refer you to the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#)

example:

```
with open('CSVFile1.csv', "rb") as csvfile:
    a = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in a:
        if user_input in row[3] and integer_input>5:
            with open('CSVFile2.csv', 'a') as f:
                new_row = row
                new_row.append(str(integer_input))
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(new_row)
                f.close()
```

Comment: I receive this error, not sure why: `writer.writerow(new_row)                                                                                                                                   
_csv.Error: sequence expected`

Comment: Well that's what I get when I post without testing :P, I missed a command, I have updated the code. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

`writerows()` does only take one parameter. The below code appends the `row[3]` to the row, then the entire row is sent to `writerow()` as its only parameter. I've also moved the writer file to outside of the loop, otherwise if more than one match occurs, you'd be overwriting it on each iteration.

```
with open('CSVFile1.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:

    fh = csv.reader(csvfile)
    wfh = open('CSVFile2.csv', 'ab')

    for row in fh:
        if user_input in row[3] and int(integer_input) > 5:
            row.append(integer_input)
            writer = csv.writer(wfh)
            writer.writerow(row)

    wfh.close()
```

Comment: For `wfh = open('overlimit.csv', 'w', newline='')` it says there is yet another type error: `TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function` :( Any ideas why?

Comment: I think you need to change the 'w' to 'wb', and remove the "newline=''" part. You may need to change the 'r' to 'rb' in the first file as well. I was testing on Python3, and some things are different.

Comment: Thanks, this also works! Just had to change 'r' to 'rb' and w to 'a' :)